# 32feet - windows 10 bluetooth beginconnect fail c#

Tags: c#, sockets, bluetooth, windows-10, 32feet

I have my phone authenticated and trying to connect to the device on windows 10, its failing as in screenshot.Device is paired and authenticated.
[non-connected sockets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGtBt.png)

Comment: Which service do you want to connect to? Are you sure your cell supports SPP?

Comment: I am trying connection to samsung s9+ but have to communicate to point of sales terminal via bluetooth. I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919276/bluetooth-pairing-ssp-on-windows-10-with-32feet-net. It show PIN popup on both(laptop and s9+) devices when code is run paired flag true. I accept on both devices but the socket error comes at the beginconnect. I am thinking do we need 2 different code for win7 and win10 separately or have to look into windows.devices.bluetooth?

Comment: I afraid I should repeat the question: Are you sure that your Samsung device supports Serial Port Profile service you are trying to connect to?