# C# BluetoothLE How can I getting started

Tags: c#, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, 32feet, plugin.bluetoothle

I am new to this business and I want to make an application related to Bluetooth LE. I don't know where to start, I want to do it using a library. I searched libraries such as 32feet.Net, InTheHand.BluetoothLe, Plugin.BluetoothLe, ble.net but I could not figure out how to make a windows form app or what can I do and where to start. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bluetooth on windows has always been difficult with very few examples to learn from.

I think the most up to date way is probably to make a UWP application and use the Windows.Devices namespace.  I've never tried it that way though.

There are examples of this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE

If you want to use 32feet.net, you will find some sample code in an old question of mine here:
[Bluetooth Pairing (SSP) on Windows 10 with 32feet.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36919276/bluetooth-pairing-ssp-on-windows-10-with-32feet-net)

I got the basics of searching for devices working, but never got the pairing to work how I wanted, and the question never got an answer despite someone placing a bounty on it.  Hopefully it at least puts you on the right path.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. It really helped. But I don't want to do it on Windows, I want to search the libraries and compare which library is better. And I want to do the application through those libraries and I could not find any documentation about the libraries, I think their contents have been changed and not updated from the documentation. I could not find any getting started, quick example, either.